# How to manage recently added host's containers and create stack for those in Rancher?

Tags: rancher

I have added a new `Host` to the `Rancher` and the host has some containers in it. I can only add a container to the new host in the `Hosts management page`.

How can I manage recently added host's containers and add `stacks` to them?

Comment: You can't manage already added container as it is considered as standalone containers in the host. You can add new stack and redeploy your containers in that stack. If you want to deploy in that host only then you can use some scheduling rule.

Comment: @KashyapMerai yes your right. scheduling rules can help.